# Cakephp Override HtmlHelper::link

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, html-helper

I want to setup HtmlHelper::link() method so the default options array have escape = false.

How can I achieve this without changing the core class?

OBS: I already sanitized form input, so I guess this will have no problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Cake 2.1.5**

I just implemented this and I wanted to point out a few things:

Your custom html helper should extend HTML helper (and don't forget to include the HTML helper class)

```
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class CustomHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
   //yadda yadda
}
```

Additionally, your call in AppController should not include the word Helper:

```
'Html'=> array('className' =>'CustomHtml'),
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Cake 2.0**

Create your OwnHelper class containing a link method, which extends HtmlHelper, in AppController specify:

```
$helpers = array('Html' => array('className' => 'OwnHelper'));
```

via ADmad

Comment: Note that the className option should not include "Helper", Cake will append that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create your own custom helper and create a method that returns the HTMLHelper's link with the options set?

http://book.cakephp.org/view/102/Including-other-Helpers

```
class MyHelper extends AppHelper {
  var $helpers = array('html');

  function linkNoEscape($title, $url)
    $options = array(); //set custom options, e.g. no escape 

    return $this->Html->link($title, $url, $options);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'll have to change the whole system. More work than just add the option on the links.

Comment: @dhofstet's solution might be useful to you then. But if you do a find and replace on every instance of existing link code, this might not be too time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

I'm never comfortable overriding methods higher up in the hierarchy (ie in AppHelper) because there is always a good chance you break other helpers that are dependent.

Hoping to be able to comment soon, instead of giving rubbish half answers!

Also relevant: I heard that CakePHP 2.0 will allow helpers, components etc to be aliased. Eg you want to change the output from HtmlHelper, you can replace it with your own version without changing all your view templates.

Comment: Whoa, thank you for pointing out the aliasing feature in 2.0 — that more or less fixes this and other similar issues. FYI, aliasing helpers in controllers is demonstrated in [Cookbook → Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the original `HTMLHelper` from `cake/libs/view/helpers` to `app/views/helpers` and modify the `link()` method there.

Comment: You should leave the original files in the `cake` folder, otherwise updates are going to be a pain.

Comment: Yes, that's a disadvantage of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

another good practice that I think cakephp should implement that you also can implement is a simple Factory Pattern Helper. The following should be consider just psuedo not real code.

```
$this->Factory->getHelper('Html')->link();
```

instead of

```
$this->Html->link();
```

take the following for example

```
class FactoryHelper extends  Helper {
    public function getHelper($name) {
        if(Configure::read('Overrides.{$name}')) {
            return $this->{Configure::read('Overrides.{$name}')};
        }
        return (isset($this->{$name})?$this->{$name}:false);
    }

}

//Bootstrap is where you will set all your overrides
Configure::write('Overrides',array(
    'Html'=>'NewHtml'
));
```

//so now when you want to override any helper you can

So now in the bootstrap that you set to override Html Helper. Throughout your entire site, your new 'NewHtml' helper will be called instead of the traditional helper.

Answer (score -3):

you can overwrite any helper method from AppHelper, so

```
class AppHelper extends Helper{
    function link($params, $go, $here){ ... code ...}
}
```

Comment: Seems pointless since the HtmlHelper extends AppHelper and defines its own `link` method, no?