# how to change .php to .html using htaccess in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp in one of my projects. ( its not about Router::connect())

I have 2 folder into webroot. every folder content 50 folder (name with state)
every state folder content related cities folder and every city folder have 5 .php file.

like

```
localhost/project_name/rooms/fl/tampa/abc.php  (/rooms{folder}/fl{folder}/tampa{folder}/ )
localhost/project_name/roommates/fl/tampa/xyz.php
```

Now i want to rewrite url like

```
localhost/project_name/rooms/fl/tampa/abc.html

localhost/project_name/roommates/fl/tampa/xyz.html
```

How can i do this via .htaccess in cakephp

Answer (score 2):

You could do with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/project_name/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project_name/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a (.*).php url to (something).html, you just have to set the relevant rule in the htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

I guess you'd better be a bit specific since if the rule is too general, it could lead to unexpected results.

Provided the host of your site is just localhost, I'd try something like this :

```
RewriteRule ^project_name/rooms/(.*)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/project_name/rooms/$1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^project_name/roommates/(.*)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/project_name/rooms/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: not working, it will redirect to localhost/index.html

Comment: How would they do this by themselves ? I guess you have conflicting rules in your htaccess. The ones above are basic rules I already use for some sites, they do work.

Comment: Cakephp also have 3 .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I understand that the OP asks for a htaccess solution, but I just want to share this as a possible answer since I don't know if the OP knows about the following method.*

---

You don't have to use .htaccess in this case. CakePHP offers a method do this for you without having to modify the .htaccess.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Products', array(
    'controller' => 'products',
    'action' => 'index',
    'ext' => 'html' // <-- this is the notable part
));
```

And in your routes.php configure .html to be an allowed extension:

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions

Also, have a look at the following question on SO for some extra insights/tips: [How can I append .html to all my URLs in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410611/how-can-i-append-html-to-all-my-urls-in-cakephp)

**Protip:** you could [extend the HtmlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654361/1110760) with a custom HtmlHelper (like MyHtmlHelper) and set `ext => html` as the default behaviour for all links you create.

Ps. I guess (didn't test it!) this method is slower than a .htaccess method since this will be handled in PHP instead of directly in the request itself. If you know what I mean ...

Comment: its not about controller and view. if we have .php file into webroot we cant use Router::....

Comment: Ah yes, I see :) But then I'm just curious, why are there so many php files in the webroot? Kinda sounds like it should be a database with just a single controller/action combination. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Just curious.

Comment: yes ita already done, but my client want that, his SEO master suggest him that we need "absolute files".

Comment: Why is that of any concern for you SEO? The Google spiders don't care if it is an "absolute file"  or a "fake"  file. All that Google cares about are the URL's ;-) So I still don't understand why absolute files are of any concern :)

Comment: I forwarded it to one of my SEO colleagues, it looks like you misunderstood your SEO master. He probably meant "Absolute URL's", not "absolute files". But of course, I could be completely in the wrong here ;-)

Comment: yes, i also try to convince my client. but he said need absolute files and folder,not dynamic. so search engine can read those static files ( we cant read file and folder structure of server). but still he want this

Comment: i already do all things via one .ctp file and Router and database but in webroot folder i cant use MVC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55142/discussion-between-jelmer-and-yogesh-saroya).